# Как в C# дать процессу права, что бы пользователь не смог его завершить через диспетчер задач?

Tags: c#, процесс

Как в C# дать процессу права, что бы пользователь не смог его завершить через диспетчер задач? Чтобы было сообщение по типу: "У вас не достаточно прав чтобы завершить процесс", "Отказано в доступе"

Comment: Погуглите, очень много ответов на ваш вопрос с примерами, потому что каждый такой случай уникальный и имеет различные варианты реализации.

Comment: А у пользователя есть права администратора?

Comment: Запуск процесса через планировщик заданий с указанием админских учетных данных.

Comment: Такая программа может вызвать ненависть к разработчику и нежелание использовать ее